# Converting multiple photos by size in php

Tags: php, arrays, forms, image

Here is my code of importing and converting a photo into database and in a path on server drive.
I want to upload multiple photos in database and convert all of them in a smaller size. For example when I press button "chose file" I want to select more than one photo , and submit all of them. After they need to go in my database, and to convert into a smaller size (all of them, not only one).

```
 <?php include("config.php") ?>
   <?php
$name = '';
$type = '';
$size = '';
$error = '';
   function compress_portrait($source_url, $destination_url, $quality) {


      $info = getimagesize($source_url);

          if ($info['mime'] == 'image/jpeg')
          $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($source_url);

          elseif ($info['mime'] == 'image/gif')
          $image = imagecreatefromgif($source_url);

          elseif ($info['mime'] == 'image/png')
          $image = imagecreatefrompng($source_url);

          imagejpeg($image, $destination_url, $quality);
          return $destination_url;
        } if ($_POST) {

            if ($_FILES["portrait"]["error"] > 0) {
            $error = $_FILES["portrait"]["error"];
        }
            else if (($_FILES["portrait"]["type"] == "image/gif") ||
            ($_FILES["portrait"]["type"] == "image/jpeg") ||
            ($_FILES["portrait"]["type"] == "image/png") ||
            ($_FILES["portrait"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")) {
                $fname=$_FILES['portrait']['name'];
            $url = ('upload/portrait/'.$fname );

            $filename = compress_portrait($_FILES["portrait"]["tmp_name"], $url, 50);
        $query="INSERT into gallery (`USER_CODE`,`FILE_NAME`,`FILE_SIZE`,`FILE_TYPE`, `CATEGORY`) VALUES('$user_id','$fname','$file_size','$file_type' , 'portrait'); ";
             mysqli_query($con , $query);

        }}else {
            $error = "Uploaded image should be jpg or gif or png";
        }

?>

<div class="container align-center" >
<h1 class="mt-3">Add Images on Gallery</h1>

<h4 style="margin-top: 12px; ">Portrait:</h4>
<form action="" method="POST" id="img_compress" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="portrait" id="portrait" multiple/>
 <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="submit btn-primary"/>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Please read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/2225619) and the guide on asking good questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and try to [edit] your question accordingly.